# Is there any full node supporting multiple crypto currencies like BTC, BCH, Litecoin?

Tags: json-rpc, altcoin

I want to use JSON-RPC protocol in my application such that it should support multiple crypto currencies.Is there any single full node supporting multiple cryptocurrencies.

Answer (score 2):

Different networks are completely independent, and while it is technically possible to put together a single node software that is able to connect and process all of them, it makes little sense for someone to invest that amount of time and money in it when you can simply run each network independently (even on the same machine).